# What's the difference/incompatibility between ng-model and ng-value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-ng-value

As far as i understood ng-model sets the value for that particular element in which the model is been assigned.
given that how is ng-value different from ng-model?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It works in conjunction with ng-model; for radios and selects, it is the value that is set to the ng-model when that item is selected. Use it as an alternative to the 'value' attribute of the element, which will always store a string value to the associated ng-model.

In the context of radio buttons, it allows you to use non-string values. For instance, if you have the radio buttons 'Yes' and 'No' (or equivalent) with values 'true' and 'false' - if you use 'value', the values stored into your ng-model will become strings. If you use 'ng-value', they will remain booleans.

In the context of a select element, however, note that the ng-value will still always be treated as a string. To set non-string values for a select, use ngOptions.

Answer (score 15):

Simple Description

**ng-model**

1. Is used for two way binding of variable that can be available on scope as well as on html.
2. which has `$modelValue`(value reside in actual scope) & `$viewValue` (value displayed on view).
3. If you mentioned on form with name attribute then angular internally creates validation attributes for it like $error, $valid, $invalid etc.

**Eg.**

```
<input type="text/checkbox/radio/number/tel/email/url" ng-model="test"/>
```

**ng-value**

1. Is used to assign value to respective `ng-model` value like `input`,
   `select` & `textarea`(same can be done by using `ng-init`)
2. `ng-value` does provide good binding if your are setting `ng-model` value through ajax while writing `value` attribute doesn't support it
3. Basically meant to use for `radio` & `option` tag while creating `select` options dynamically.
4. It can only have `string` value it, it doesn't support object value.

**HTML**

```
<input
  [ng-value="string"]>
...
</input>
```

**OR**

```
<select ng-model="selected">
  <option ng-value="option.value" ng-repeat="option in options">
     {{option.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

...

Answer (score 3):

A good use for `ng-value` in `input` fields is if you want to bind to a variable, but based on another variable's value. Example:

```
<h1>The code is {{model.code}}.</h1>
<p>Set the new code: <input type="text" ng-bind="model.code" /></p>
```

When the user types in the `input`, the value in the title will be updated. If you don't want this, you can modify to:

```
<input type="text" ng-value="model.code" ng-bind="model.theNewCode" />
```

`theNewCode` will be updated, but `code` will remain untouched.

Answer (score 2):

According to the https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue, **ngValue** takes an "angular expression, whose value will be bound to the value attribute of the input element".

So, when you use ng-value="hard", it is interpreted as an expression and the value is bound to $scope.hard (which is probably undefined).
ngValue is useful for evaluating expressions - it has no advantage over value for setting hard-coded values. Yet, if you want to hard-code a value with ngValue, you must enclose it in '':

ng-value="'hard'"

**ng-model** is intended to be put inside of form elements and has two-way data binding ($scope --> view and view --> $scope) e.g. `<input ng-model="val"/>.`

or you can say The **ng-model** directive binds the value of HTML controls (input, select, textarea) to application data.

Comment: i was looking for the difference between *ng-model* and *ng-value*

Comment: Please note that 'ng-value' does have an advantage over hard-coding to the element attribute 'value', in that you can specify non-string types. For example, 'true' and 'false' will be stored to the model as booleans, rather than as strings.

Comment: Also `ngValue` is a one-way binding, and `ngModel` is a two-way binding.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation clearly states that `ng-value` should not be used when doing **two-way** binding with `ng-model`.

From the Docs:

> ## ngValue
>
> Binds the given expression to the value of the element.
>
> It can also be used to achieve **one-way** binding of a given expression to an input element such as an `input[text]` or a `textarea`, **when that element does not use** `ngModel`.
>
> — [AngularJS `ng-value` Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue)

Instead, initialize the value from the controller:

Comment: That's NOT what the documentation says.  It say don't use both ng-value and ng-model on either text or textareas.  For radio, check, option, it's perfectly fine to use together.

Comment: Even in the case of radio buttons, changes in the variable bound by the `ng-value` directive will not update the variable bound by the `ng-model` directive. The `ng-value` will only update its bound variable when the user clicks or selects that radio button.

Comment: That is by design though.  If the underlying value of the radio button changes that should invalidate the user's original selection not magically select it for them.  Just consider a radio button that shifts between deposit and withdraw.  That would be a serious issue if the user selected deposit and some how the UI changed it to withdraw.

Comment: The fact remains that the `ng-model` directive ignores AngularJS framework changes to the variable bound by the `ng-value` directive. The `ng-model` directive only reacts to user input.