# ng-model on hidden file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

EDITED:

Now I'm trying this way

```
<input class="form-check-input deflog-check" type="checkbox" ngTrueValue = "1" ngFalseValue = "0" ng-value="chk_mail">
```

Ang getting the vahlue innangular like this

`object2Edit.notificacion = Number($scope.chk_mail) + Number($scope.chk_mail)`;

but  $scope.chk_mail is Nan

Comment: it is not a really good practice to manipulate the DOM with jQuery inside angular. To set the element's value, you should use the controller variable you bind.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
ng-value
```

to

```
ng-model
```

good explanation on difference between two can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/28718132/7104041

EDIT:

just noticed other things. You should change this

```
<input class="form-check-input deflog-check" type="checkbox" ngTrueValue = "1" ngFalseValue = "0" ng-value="chk_mail">
```

to

```
<input class="form-check-input deflog-check" type="checkbox" ng-true-value= "1" ng-false-value = "0" ng-model="chk_mail">
```

and have your chk_mail assigned in controller

https://plnkr.co/edit/i9JdNnMAiK3O9No768Ei?p=preview

you can see how it works in this plunker