# ng-submit give old value after form submit

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-1.6

i'm new in angularjs, **ng-submit** give old value after form submit

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.myTxt = "You have not yet clicked submit";
  $scope.sidebarname = "Vendor";
  $scope.myFunc = function () {
      $scope.myTxt = "You clicked submit!";
      alert($scope.sidebarname);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<form ng-submit="myFunc()">
  <input ng-value="sidebarname" type="text">
  <input  type="submit">
</form>

<p>{{myTxt}}</p>



</div>
```

after form submit **$scope.sidebarname** give old value **Vendor** , i have read and search about it but nothing helpful.

**any help or suggestion will be helpful**

Comment: Use ng-model for input's value

Comment: `ng-value` will do one way binding... the change in `sidebarname` will not reflect in its model. for the same use `ng-model`

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<form ng-submit="myFunc()">
  <input ng-model="sidebarname" type="text">
  <input  type="submit">
</form>
```

Note: `ng-model` is [different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717523/whats-the-difference-between-ng-model-and-ng-value) from `ng-value`

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.myTxt = "You have not yet clicked submit";
  $scope.sidebarname = "Vendor";
  $scope.myFunc = function () {
      $scope.myTxt = "You clicked submit!";
      alert($scope.sidebarname);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<form ng-submit="myFunc()">
  <input ng-model="sidebarname" type="text">
  <input  type="submit">
</form>

<p>{{myTxt}}</p>



</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To bind the value from HTML page and controller we should use `ng-model`.
In your case, it is always taking the value from the controller and not getting binded by the value from your HTML page.

`ng-value` is different from `ng-model`

```
<form ng-submit="myFunc()">
     <input ng-model="sidebarname" type="text">
     <input  type="submit">
</form>

<p>{{myTxt}}</p>
```