# ng-value does not update Ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I set the input value Array property sum and it shows value in input but when submitting form does not get `Quantity` property in `Order` object. If I change the value then I get `Quantity` property value. How can I get model value from `ng-value`?

```
<input ng-model="Order.Quantity" ng-value="subOrderList.sum('Quantity')" type="number">
```

Comment: why are you using both `ng-model` *and* `ng-value` ? You just need one.

Comment: For set default value

Comment: Thats not how it works, you cant use both.

Comment: [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717523/whats-the-difference-between-ng-model-and-ng-value)

Comment: Isaac is absolutely right  - You set the default value to the property that is bound to the `ngModel` directive from the controller (Or using the `ngInit` directive if you prefer)

Comment: @AlonEitan I need to get updated value from an array and my array is changing for this reason `ngInit` is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, "ng-value does not update Ng-model", it is by design.  As mentioned in comments, `ng-value` and `ng-model` are not intended to by used in this way.

It isn't entirely clear what you are trying to achieve here, so here's a couple potential solutions:

If you are just looking to display a value then you don't need to use an input at all.  Both of these will behave the same and update when needed:

```
<span>{{subOrderList.sum('Quantity')}}</span>

<span ng-bind="subOrderList.sum('Quantity')"></span>
```

If you actually need this value to be updated by user input then the HTML would look like this:

```
<input ng-model="Order.Quantity" type="number">
```

And then you will need to manually update that value in a controller or service when needed:

```
Order.Quantity = subOrderList.sum('Quantity');
```

From your comments it almost seems like you need an input that also changes dynamically and sporadically, but without a data example or more code I can't really see how that would work.