# Angularjs problem using ng-model and `value` together

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form and this form have some values. Input values are set using json data:

```
<input name="name" ng-model='user.name' value="{{user.name}}">
```

I want to use a different `ng-model`:

```
<input name="isim" ng-model='userProfile.name' value="{{user.name}}">
```

This destroy values from `<input />`.

- How can I use json data and different ng-model in input?
- How do you update a form with AngularJS?

Comment: Please could you explain what do you mean by input values destroys?

Comment: what do u mean by destroys

Comment: When i using json data {{user.name}} and ng-model='formData.name', input value disapear. But if i using ng-model='user.name' its working. But i want to use ng-model='formData.name' and showing json data same time.

Comment: You should check how two-way data binding works in angular

Comment: there is something called one-time binding {{ ::vm.user }} , it will bind for the first digest cycle after that it will remove the association with the model, can u try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using an interpolated `value` attribute with `ng-model`:

```
<input name="name" ng-model='user.name' ̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶=̶"̶{̶{̶u̶s̶e̶r̶.̶n̶a̶m̶e̶}̶}̶" >

<input name="isim" ng-model='userProfile.name'  ̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶=̶"̶{̶{̶u̶s̶e̶r̶.̶n̶a̶m̶e̶}̶}̶" >
```

Instead intialize the value from the controller:

```
$scope.userProfile.name = $scope.user.name;
```

The `ng-model` creates a two-way binding that will fight the one-way binding of the interpolated `value` attribute.

For more information, see [whats the difference between `ng-model` and `ng-value`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717523/whats-the-difference-between-ng-model-and-ng-value)